# Be a partner, CTO or just a freelancer?

Tags: shares

I am a programmer not good enough with business. I am doing a project for one of my clients. It's a new software product he wants to introduce; he's so confident that he wants me to be CTO of the company/product he is going to launch and hold shares in it. I am just a freelancer. I've no problem being future CTO of soon to appear company. I am confused how and what should I negotiate with him? How many % of share should I claim as CTO as I'll be supporting all techie stuff including software and IT infrastructure. Or should I just claim my charges as a freelance project?

This is not a technical question so I asked here...

Comment: Is this an ongoing enterprise or a proposal?  Does he have an entity formed?  Is your business run through an entity or just sole proprietorship?

Comment: Another thing to consider:  How long have you worked with this person? How well does he know your work habits? If the client is handing out jobs left and right to anyone nearby, do you really want to hitch your wagon to his train?

Answer (score 3):

I write software myself and was involved in a couple of start ups.  One failed, another was wildly successful, but I did not receive much in compensation.

The former I received stock, but since it failed, it was worthless anyway.  There should be compensation for your time in addition to equity in a company.

Any agreement needs be in writing.  In the later situation I was told to expect about a 17%/year bonus, but nothing could be guaranteed.  Translation:  "It will never happen."  It didn't, but I meet my lovely wife there so I have that for a bonus.

Agreements need to address the bad things can happen.  What happens if one of you is no longer interested in continuing?  What happens if one of you die, or addicted to something?  What happens if one of you gets thrown in jail or disabled?  Right now you are full of optimism and hope, but bad things happen.  Cover those things while you still like each other.

It might be enough to have a good salary, and some stock options.  You man not be interested in running the day to day business.

Most of all good luck, I wish you all the best!

Answer (score 2):

First, determine the workload he will expect.  Will you have to quit your other work, either for time or for competition?  How much of your current business will be subsumed into his business, if any?  Make sure to understand what he wants from you.  If you make an agreement, set it in writing and set some clear expectations about what will happen to your business (e.g. it continues and is not part of your association with the client).  Because he was a client for your current business, it can blur the lines.

Second, if you join him, make sure there is a business entity.  By working together for profit, you will have already formed a partnership for tax purposes.  Best to get an entity, both for the legal protection and also for the clarity of law and accounting.  LLCs are simplest for small ventures; C corps are useful if you have lots of early losses and owners that can't use them personally, or if you want to be properly formed for easy consumption by a strategic.  Most VCs and super-angels prefer everybody be a straight C.  Again, remember to define, as necessary, what you are contributing to be an owner and what you are retaining (your original business, which for simplicity may already be in an entity).  As part of this process, make sure he defines the cap table and any outstanding loans.  Auntie June and Cousin Steve might think their gifts to him were loans or equity purchases; best to clear this issue up early before there's any more money in it.

Third, with regard to price, that is an intensely variable question.  It matters what the cap table looks like, how early you are, how much work he's already done, how much work remains to be done, and how much it will pay off.  Also, if you do it, expect to be diluted by other employees, angels, VCs, other investors, strategics, and so on.  Luckily, more investors usually indicates a growing pie, so the dilution may not be at all painful.  But it should still be on your horizon.  You also need to consider your faith in your prospective partner's ability to run the business and to be a trustworthy partner (so you don't get Zuckerberg'd), and to market the business and the product to customers and investors.

If you don't like the prospects, then opt for cash.  If you like the business but want to hedge, ask for compensation plus equity.  There are other tricks you could use to get out early, like forced redemption, but they probably wouldn't help either because it'd sour your relationship or the first VC or knowledgeable angel to come along will want you to relinquish that sort of right.

It probably comes down to a basic question of your need for cash, his willingness to let you pursue outside work (hopefully high) and your appraisal of the business' prospects.

Answer (score 1):

Being a CTO is different than freelancing, obviously.  You have to ask yourself what you would more prefer to do!

My initial recommendation would be to receive your normal freelance compensation for the freelance work you do AND separately deal with the issue of being a CTO.  At some point you will cease to be this project's freelancer should you become its CTO.

Then again, by becoming the CTO immediately you should be able to negotiate a larger share of the company.

Granted, my opinions should not be considered legal or financial advice and you should consult a professional before making any decisions.  Ja ja ja  ;)